# lighttpd and php 403 - Forbidden

Tags: linux, lighttpd

I'm trying to upload a xml file using lighttpd and php into linux board.

Unfortenly, I get a 403 - Forbidden error.

No errors into error.log.

No fcgi.

web_root folder has

```
chown -R root:root /web_root
```

**Ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cid/filename.cid",
    method: "PUT",
    data: xmlCID,
    dataType: "xml",
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert(jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**lighttpd conf**

```
server.modules              = (
                               "mod_rewrite",
                                "mod_access",
                               "mod_auth",
                               "mod_cgi",
                                "mod_accesslog" )

server.document-root        = "/home/web_root/"
server.errorlog             = "/home/lighttpd.error.log"

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                                "index.htm", "default.htm" )

server.event-handler = "poll" # needed on OS X

server.tag                 = "lighttpd/1.4.11 (Win32)"

accesslog.filename          = "/home/access.log"

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

server.upload-dirs = ( "/var/tmp/lighttpd-upload/" )
```

Comment: Can you give more details. What is "/cid/filename.cid"? Which user is running lighttpd?

Comment: "/cid/filename.cid" is file to upload in /cid folder. filename.cid is a XML file. Lighttpd user is root. In lighttpd.conf server.username and server.groupname lines are commented

Comment: /cid/filename.cid should be a URL on the server which responds to your file upload. For example a PHP script, that achieves the data (xmlCID) and stores it on the server. The server doesn't store a file automatically. Furthermore you should never run the server as root. If there is a security vulnerability on your system, anybody can take over the whole system.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to lighttpd.conf, restart the server, re-run your request, and then check the your lighttpd.error.log.

```
debug.log-request-handling = "enable"
```

(Did you intend to write the error log directly into /home/ ?)

Is fastcgi or CGI enabled to run the PHP on your server?  I presume you left those lines out of the lighttpd.conf posted above.  Check that the PHP is being executed.  Does it log requests to a separate log file?  Check that the PHP has write permission to the location to which you are writing the file.